# Migration to Windows Azure

Tags: azure-storage, progress-db

In our organization we are using Hyper-V VMs. We are using Progress Database and apps in the workstations.

For us to migrate into the Microsoft Azure cloud, do we have to migrate our existing Progress database to SQL and rewrite our apps ?

Answer (score 0):

No. You haven't given us much detail about your applications or architecture, but if I make the assumption that you are using the embedded database product by Progress software, then I see no reason that can't run on an [Azure VM](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/).